# GPX route generator for android

Tags: android, gpx

I am looking for a free, easy to use android app or mobile friendly website to plan a route and save it in GPX format.
So far I have seen https://mapstogpx.com/ which unfortunately does not work with google maps app url and https://www.gpxgenerator.com/ which works but in a rather convoluted way for my purposes, needing to copy the resulting gpx, paste it in a new file and save.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not an app for android but worth to try:

1. http://map.project-osrm.org
2. https://graphhopper.com/maps/

And you can get and downlod the gpx file

Comment: Thanks, I have seen graphhopper before, but its interface is not really well suited for mobile browser.
project-osrm looks better, but still a little clunky for my preference. If nothing else comes up, I will use this one.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, but what I found to be the easiest way I think at the moment, is opening google maps in the desktop view of the mobile browser (not the app), generating the route there, then copying the link to maptogpx.com which downloads it as a gpx.